# How to download a source package from an ubuntu version and rebuild it for a previous ubuntu version

Tags: apt, source

The `python3-pychromecast` source package does not exist from Ubuntu Xenial official Ubuntu repositories.

I want to download the [Ubuntu Bionic python3-pychromecast](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3-pychromecast) source package and rebuild it on Ubuntu Xenial :

```bash
$ sudo apt-get build-dep python3-pychromecast/bionic-universe
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for python3-pychromecast/bionic-universe
$ apt-get source --compile python3-pychromecast/bionic-universe
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for python3-pychromecast
```

EDIT0 : Downloaded and extracted the source package :

```bash
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pychromecast/pychromecast_0.8.1-1.dsc http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pychromecast/pychromecast_0.8.1.orig.tar.gz http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pychromecast/pychromecast_0.8.1-1.debian.tar.xz 
--2020-05-27 11:50:58--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pychromecast/pychromecast_0.8.1-1.dsc
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 2001:67c:1360:8001::23, 2001:67c:1360:8001::24, 2001:67c:1562::15, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|2001:67c:1360:8001::23|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2205 (2,2K)
Saving to: ‘pychromecast_0.8.1-1.dsc’

pychromecast_0.8.1-1.dsc      100%[=================================================>]   2,15K  --.-KB/s    in 0,001s  

2020-05-27 11:50:58 (3,24 MB/s) - ‘pychromecast_0.8.1-1.dsc’ saved [2205/2205]

--2020-05-27 11:50:58--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pychromecast/pychromecast_0.8.1.orig.tar.gz
Reusing existing connection to [archive.ubuntu.com]:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 37130 (36K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘pychromecast_0.8.1.orig.tar.gz’

pychromecast_0.8.1.orig.tar.g 100%[=================================================>]  36,26K  --.-KB/s    in 0,03s   

2020-05-27 11:50:58 (1,37 MB/s) - ‘pychromecast_0.8.1.orig.tar.gz’ saved [37130/37130]

--2020-05-27 11:50:58--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pychromecast/pychromecast_0.8.1-1.debian.tar.xz
Reusing existing connection to [archive.ubuntu.com]:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3208 (3,1K) [application/x-xz]
Saving to: ‘pychromecast_0.8.1-1.debian.tar.xz’

pychromecast_0.8.1-1.debian.t 100%[=================================================>]   3,13K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2020-05-27 11:50:58 (50,8 MB/s) - ‘pychromecast_0.8.1-1.debian.tar.xz’ saved [3208/3208]

FINISHED --2020-05-27 11:50:58--
Total wall clock time: 0,2s
Downloaded: 3 files, 42K in 0,03s (1,53 MB/s)
$ dpkg-source -x pychromecast_0.8.1-1.dsc 
dpkg-source: info: extracting pychromecast in pychromecast-0.8.1
dpkg-source: info: unpacking pychromecast_0.8.1.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: unpacking pychromecast_0.8.1-1.debian.tar.xz
```

EDIT1 : Trying to build :

```bash
$ debuild -i -us -uc -b
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc -i -b
dpkg-buildpackage: source package pychromecast
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.8.1-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Ruben Undheim <ruben.undheim@gmail.com>
 dpkg-source -i --before-build pychromecast-0.8.1
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture i386
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: python3-protobuf
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc -i -b failed
$ dpkg-checkbuilddeps
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: python3-protobuf
$ grep python3-protobuf debian/control 
               python3-protobuf,
Depends: ${python3:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, python3-zeroconf, python3-protobuf (>= 3)
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: What you are trying to do is called *backporting*. It's not a beginner-level activity. You may need to backport and build multiple dependencies to get the main package to work. Get the source at http://packages.ubuntu.com

Comment: Also try to install binary packages directly. They are mostly python scripts, so may work without real compilation.

Comment: @N0rbert I've download and extracted the source (see my EDIT0). What is the debian/ubuntu command to build the package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you download the source archives:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pychromecast/pychromecast_0.8.1.orig.tar.gz
tar -xf pychromecast_0.8.1.orig.tar.gz
cd pychromecast-0.8.1/

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pychromecast/pychromecast_0.8.1-1.debian.tar.xz
tar -xf pychromecast_0.8.1-1.debian.tar.xz
```

Then install build-dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install debhelper dh-python python-all python-setuptools python3-all python3-setuptools python3-protobuf python3-requests python3-zeroconf
```

**but it will not work because of missed `python3-protobuf` debian package and Python 3.5 in 16.04 LTS**.

Then build the package with

```
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
```

---

So I would recommend to install the [package from PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/PyChromecast/):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install PyChromecast
```

Comment: @Norbert Why does the [ubuntu bionic python3-protobuf package depend on `Python >= 3.6`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3-protobuf) instead of 3.5 when Python3.5 is enough to `pip3 install protobuf` on ubuntu xenial ?

Comment: It's a pity. If python3.5 is enough than I guess I could use the same procedure to build `python3-protobuf` package in xenial myself.

Comment: Do have any idea why they didn't package `protobuf` in ubuntu xenial if it supports python v3.5 ?

Comment: I do not know really.